# I want to access the array of object as defined below

Tags: javascript

```js
items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'apple'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'mango'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'strawberry'
    }]
```

And i want to access it like this -> var all = apple, mango, strawberry

Comment: `var all = whatever.items.map(({ name }) => name)`

Comment: what's the intent of var all = apple, mango, strawberry. where are you going to use that as in this eg all will hold the last value of after the comma.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.  Do you want each `name` inside your `items` array to be concatenated into a string separated by a comma? And if so, why?

Comment: Please provide more details. It's too short string and too hard to understand what you want exactly.